# Is news aggregation for headlines only legal?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Is it legal to display recent news that are collected from multiple news sites on my page?
The goal is to show daily news (100 articles), side by side, that are collected from an api.
Single instance of an article would hold only the headline, date published and a link to the original article (their page).
No paywalls, no advertisements. Maybe an option to donate, if someone wants to, but no benefits from that.
The readers would have the ability to lookup older articles also.
Read some stuff online on this subject, but didn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: Depends on the country. In areas like the EU or Australia, weird laws for news aggregators are on the rise that might require payments to publishers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the US, 99.9% of commercial, non-profit or free news web sites have Terms of Service agreements, which are legally binding documents that come into effect when you access their site by reading or scraping.

Those TOSs state what exactly you can do with their content, how you can access it, if you can use their API or not. how you can reuse it, with or without a link back to the original article, etc.

Read the TOS for each news site you want to scrape and you'll learn a lot; chances are very good they forbid scraping, or they may allow scraping with a license granted to you to reuse their content.

Respect the legal bounds of each TOS or you may find yourself in civil court.

Scraping only headlines *could* be seen as Fair Use, but a court would make the ultimate decison. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use#Internet_publication

The only "definitive answer" you're going to need is from an attorney you hire, because this site is not for legal advice.

Making no money or asking for donations for your site does not mitigate your copyright infringement.

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciated!